# How to efficiently convert Python structures to serde_json::Value?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

**Context**

I implemented a Rust library for JSON Schema validation which operates with `serde_json::Value` instances. Now I want to use it from Python and considering `PyO3` as my primary choice for connecting them. Python values should be converted to `serde_json::Value` when passed to the library and `serde_json::Value` should be converted back to Python inside validation errors returned by the Rust part.

One of the possible ways will be implementing `serde::se::Serialize` for a newtype wrapper around `pyo3::types::PyAny` and then passing it to `serde_json::to_value`, but I am not sure how efficient it will be. What are the options and what trade-offs are there?

From Python side I mostly interested in built-in types, that are serializable by `json.dumps`, without custom classes at the moment.

Rust-side example:

```
use jsonschema::{JSONSchema, Draft, CompilationError};
use serde_json::Value;

pub fn is_valid(schema: &Value, instance: &Value) -> bool {
    let compiled = JSONSchema::compile(schema, None).expect("Invalid schema");
    compiled.is_valid(instance)
}
```

I.e. there is a [function](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L53) that accepts two references to `serde_json::Value` and I want to expose it to Python. From the Python side there might be two use-cases:

1. The instance is a JSON-encoded string:

```
import jsonschema_rs

assert jsonschema_rs.is_valid(
    {"minItems": 2}, 
    "[1, 2]"
)
```

2. The instance is a Python structure (not a JSON-encoded string):

```
import jsonschema_rs

assert jsonschema_rs.is_valid(
    {"minItems": 2},
    [1, 2]
)
```

**Possible use-cases**

1. Web app request/response structure validation.

   - When a request going in, then its body is validated as is, without parsing according to the schema.
   - When a response is returned, this structure is validated according to the schema before serializing to JSON;

In the future, both steps might be combined with Rust-powered JSON deserialization (on the request side) and deserialization (on the response side).

2. Using for property-based testing as an extension for [Hypothesis](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis)

In this case, the faster the input is validation, the more test cases are generated. Current [implementation](https://github.com/Zac-HD/hypothesis-jsonschema) uses Python [library](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) under the hood which is quite slow for complex schemas that I am working with usually.

**Update**

I tried to implement `Serialize` trait [here](https://github.com/Stranger6667/pyo3-example/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L14) and added a comparison with raw string input as suggested by @Sven Marnach in comments. Indeed, the raw string is the fastest option, but if it involves calling `json.dumps` in Python it goes significantly worse than the variant with the trait.

Small objects & schema (100000 iterations):

```
String        : 1.31617
Trait         : 1.52797 (x1.16)
String + dumps: 2.77378 (x2.1)
```

Big objects & schema (100 iterations):

```
String        : 1.42146
Trait         : 3.70745 (x2.6)
String + dumps: 6.21213 (x4.37)
```

Benchmark [code and test data](https://github.com/Stranger6667/pyo3-example/blob/master/bench.py).

Having a version for strings definitely makes sense, but calling `json.dumps` is quite expensive. I don't know if there are any better options for such scenarios.

**Python version**: 3.7

**Rust version**: 1.42.0

**Dependencies**:

- serde_json = "1.0.48"
- serde = "1.0.105"
- jsonschema = "0.2.0"

Comment: The simplest solution for a first version is to use Python's own JSON serialization in the `json` module, and only pass the serialized string to Rust. Chances are this is good enough.

Comment: Indeed, it works, but implies `json.dumps` overhead on the Python side, which, I assume, will be bigger than converting Python structure on the Rust side after some input size. But probably it is the best option when there is no JSON serialization on the Python size and the input is available as a string

Comment: Implementing a direct conversion for a reasonable subset of Python's built-in types to `serde_json::Value` probably isn't too bad, but it's definitely a non-trivial amount of work, so I'd only do it if profiling shows that it's necessary.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to my straightforward trait implementation (I am not sure if it is correct for all cases, but seems to be working) and a benchmark. Calling `json.dumps` is quite expensive, but raw string is the fastest option

Comment: Your implementation for the conversion directly to `Value` is a bit easier than I expected. Looks nice!

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanks, it looks like it works for a general case. Are there some areas where that implementation could be improved? However, probably this discussion should be on  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: At a glance, the implementation looks fine to me. I'm not sure I'd support other key types than strings – JSON doesn't, after all, and serializing a Python object like `{None: 1, "null": 2}` could lead to rather unexpected results. I know Python's `json` module does the same, but that's just as questionable. :) Moreover, `is_normal()` seems a bit stronger than you need – `is_finite()` should be sufficient.

Comment: It appears you deleted the repo with the code you linked. Would adding the code as part of the post instead?